# sklearn model is not being fitted due to bad input shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the following model for a multilabel problem.

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', 
                alpha=1e-3, random_state=42, 
                max_iter=5, tol=None)
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X, Y = vect.fit_transform(X_raw), mlb.fit_transform(Y_raw)
X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)
clf.fit(X_Train,Y_Train)
predict = clf.predict(X_Test)
predict_label = mlb.inverse_transform(predict)
```

Please note `X.shape` is `(829,565)` and `Y.shape` is `(829,251)`
Now I am getting the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-101-5e447893b03c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/Testing/model_build_mlb.py', wdir='D:/Testing')

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Testing/model_build_mlb.py", line 1715, in <module>
clf.fit(X_Train,Y_Train)

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 586, in fit
sample_weight=sample_weight)

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py", line 418, in _fit
X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 578, in check_X_y
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

File "C:\Users\ce\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 614, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (555, 251)
```

Is it due to the model? Or anything else? 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SGDClassifier` is explicitly demanding that you give it a 1d array with your labels (`Y_train`). It doesn't take multilabel problems like you're giving it. You need to wrap it in something like `OneVsRestClassifier`

Comment: @CJ59: Many thanks. Just for my curiosity, does by any mean OneVsRestClassifier solves the imbalanced training set error? I mean the classifier is not able to predict the correct class due to very small representation of that class in the training data. How can I rectify the imbalanced training set?

Comment: There are no good answers to that. `StratifiedKFold` crossvalidation and stratifying your train-test split will help. You could try oversampling one class, or you could filter out a lot of your overrepresented class.

Comment: What you really need is better data. Good luck.